# Inserting into database using a PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert data into a database that I have on my server.

To connect to my database I have the following code:

```
<?php
$host = "/homes/49/jc192699/public_html/dbase/";
$database = "EduPro.db";
$dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);

try {
    $dbhandle = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);

} catch (PDOException $e) {

echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and this all works fine! I have included this into my code so that is not the issue.

Here is my code for inserting data into the database:

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (`userName`, `password`) VALUES (`test, `testy`)";
  if ( $fetched = $dbhandle->query($sql)){
  $fetched->execute(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
  echo "Success!";
  }

  else {
echo "Fail.";
}

?>
```

It is not inserting the data into the database for some reason. I know that the SQL statement is 100% correct as I have tested it elsewhere.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are opening two database connection. change your code to

```
$host = "/homes/49/jc192699/public_html/dbase/";
$database = "EduPro.db";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

you should not use backquote instead using single quote in your query. and also column should not have any quotes.

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (userName, password) VALUES ('test', 'testy')";
    $sth = $conn->query($sql);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

to fetch the records you need to use this

```
try {
    $sth = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM USERS');
    $rows = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //$rows contains the fetched records in an associative array
    var_dump($rows);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

learn more about PDO here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object`

Comment: oops i am sorry, you cannot use a fetchall method here, since you are only inserting it and not fetching

Comment: What method should I be using then? Thank you!

Comment: i have updated my code, remove `fetchAll()` line of code and it should work

Comment: I have tried this, and although it doesn't give me an error anymore, it is still not inserting into the database :(

Comment: if there is not error then it means the record is being inserted. how are you checking wether record is being inserted or not?

Comment: How can I check whether it is being inserted?

Comment: make another select query and fetch the data. ill update my answer with the code to fetch the records.

Comment: let me know if it works, and try learning more about PDO from the link in my answer. and also mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you back-ticking the values? Try just single quotes:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (userName, password) VALUES ('test', 'testy')";
```

Also, check your PHP error log, it may give you some insight.

And according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), I believe you have to use `exec()` vs `query()`, for doing non-select queries such as inserting, updating, and deleting. If you plan on passing in variables to the `$sql` variable, you should also read up on [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some syntax rules to follow:

The SQL query must be quoted in PHP
String values inside the SQL query must be quoted
Numeric values must not be quoted
The word NULL must not be quoted

```
 If(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usersdata (Firstname, Lastname, 
Email,Passward)
VALUES (:name, :lstname, :email,:pass)");

// inserting a record
```

then Bind the Values with your variables it will work

Answer (score 0):

For a better-secured Database data insertion into the database, I believe your code should look more like this.

```
// First make your Database connections like so.
$host = "/homes/49/jc192699/public_html/dbase/";
$database = "EduPro.db";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:".$host.$database);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//then next we make the data insertion using a prepared statement.
// Try to insert the data to the database

try {
    $username = "test";
    $password = "testy";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (userName, password) VALUES ('test', 'testy')";
    $sth = $conn->query($sql);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usersdata (userName, password) VALUES (:uname, :pass)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Data inserted "; //Just get a success message

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```