# How to insert session username into mySql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, session-variables

I'm trying to write a program where the user adds data into the database and the username of the user is also entered without doing it manually.
This is the php code

```
$user->createSession(array(
             'title' => Input::get('title'),
             'start_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Input::get('start_date'))),
             'end_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Input::get('end_date'))),
             'passcode' => (Input::get('passcode')),
             'username' => (Input::get('username'))
         ));
```

This is the htlml

```
<form class="session" action="" method="POST" >
  <div class="input-group">

<label for="title" ><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Title</span></label>

<input type="text" id="username" name="title" class="form-control" value = "<?php echo escape(input::get('title')); ?>" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="on" required> 
  </div>

<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" name="start_date" placeholder="start date"></input>

  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>

<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" name="end_date" placeholder="end date"></input>
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>

  <label for="passcode" class="input-group">Pass-code (optional)</label>
    <input type="passcode" id="passcode" name="passcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Passcode" autocomplete="off" >

    <br>
    <input type = "hidden" name = "username" value = "<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>">

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
```

It adds everything into the database except the username session. I'm not sure what to do. I also tried removing:

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "username" value = "<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>">
```

And did:

```
$user->createSession(array(
         'title' => Input::get('title'),
         'start_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Input::get('start_date'))),
         'end_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(Input::get('end_date'))),
         'passcode' => (Input::get('passcode')),
         'username' => $user->data()->username
     ));
```

This is the database code as requested

```
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql'     => array(
    'host'      => 'localhost', 
    'username'  => 'root', 
    'password'  => '', 
    'db' => 'coursework'),
        //remember me
    'remember' => array('cookie_name' => 'hash', 'cookie_expiry' => '604800'),

'session' => array('session_name' => 'user', 'token_name' => 'token'));

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```

EDIT

This code inserts data into the database

```
 public function createSession($fields = array()){
    if(!$this->_db->insert('sessions', $fields)){
        throw new Exception ("there was a problem adding a session");
    }
}
```

Everything else works, the db connection works and the data is entered into the db fine but the username field is empty. The sessions being created is something else like subjects.

Connects to the DB

```
function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') .';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        //echo 'connected';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: You need some database interaction, that would be a good start. The connection doesn't just happen automatically and you haven't shown any effort to do it.

Comment: @Jonast92 I have already connected to the database with "require_once 'core/init.php';" The data does enter the database, the session variabloe doesn't.

Comment: show your Database code then..

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 I have added the database code

Comment: We need to see the code where you are inserting the data into your database, meaning we need to see some sort of code where you connect to the database and insert the desired values. What you first provided is just the connection information to your database

Comment: 1. learn how to connect to a database. 2. learn how to insert into a database. 3. take the session information and insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to insert session username into mySql database

1. You need to [connect](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) to an actual database with your configuration information,.

PDO is nice for this:

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

2. You need to [insert](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) into the database, preferrably using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

There are lots of [decent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424377/inserting-into-database-using-a-pdo) answers on *how* although I like mixing it up with the [prepared statement article](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) wherea you should be executing an array of variables into the prepared query.

3. Get the session information

You can probably figure out how to do it. Maybe there are some other information?

```
$someValue = ""; // Just some random value.
$someSessionValue = ""; // Extract from session. Probably $_SESSION['stuff'] or similar.
```

4. Finally, insert the extracted information.

Something like this should do, take a better look on the links or do a proper search:

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sql->execute(array($someValue, $someSessionValue));
```

5. If you wish to make this happen automatically then you just put this into a method that you make your code call automatically when some action is triggered.

Comment: thanks, your suggestions on extracting from the session helped.

Comment: @Love You're welcome. Feel free to tick the checkbox mark on the question and by all means ask a new question if you get stuck after elaborating on this information.