# unable to show return data via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created a query it was working before but when i tried to get data in json format though it is not working i do not know why it is not showing data in return here is my code. when I checked the console the return data is not showing though not even it is processing I think so but I am unable to rectify the problem the bug. can any one please help me out.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#addcart").on('submit', (function(e) {
        var oldval   = $('#crtcount').text();
        var form     = this;
        var formData = new FormData(this);
         $.ajax({
            url         : "includes/get_data.php",
            type        : "POST",
            data        : formData,
            contentType : false,
            cache       : false,
            processData : false,
            dataType    : "JSON",
            success     : function(data) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#crtcount').html(parseInt(oldval)+1);
                $('#crtcount1').html(parseInt(oldval)+1);
                $('#cart_dt').html(data.cart);
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

his is my php code which I have created for processing the data

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
echo $cart->add_to_cart($pid);

$data['message']  = "<div class='message'>Your product is added to cart</div>";
$data['cart']     = '';
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['pid'] as $content) { 
    $prod_id          = $content['prod_id'];
    $products         = bgMysqlSelect("SELECT * FROM bg_products WHERE pid = '$prod_id'");
    $data['cart']    .= '<div class="items-sm"><div class="img-sm"><img src="../includes/uploads'.$products['pimage'].'" /></div>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<div class="cart-inf-sm"><h4>'.$products['ptitle'].'</h4>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<p><span>price :</span>$'.$products['pmsrp'].'</p>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<p><span>Qty :</span>'.$content['qty'].'</p>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></div>';
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: can you check F12 network tab to understand wheather your php work or not

Comment: @hasan i checked the network ab and I only see this i do not know how to check in network tab about the bug

Comment: press f12 then click network tab and then click XHR filter you will see XHR requests

Comment: remove this line `echo $cart->add_to_cart($pid);`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef No I am still not getting any thing when I remove json_encode and echo only hello world and change datatype to text t works for me

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef when I changed data type to text and echo "hEllo world" and now it is working fine I do not know why Json data type is not working

Comment: remove `echo $cart->add_to_cart($pid);` from php and `var data = $.parseJSON(data);` from js .. then `console.log(data);` and `console.log(data.cart);` and `console.log(data.message);`

Comment: @UsmanKhan and try to define `$data = array();` on top of php

Comment: no still not working :-( is my code correctly written jquery and php am i doing something wrong? this is what shows in network when clicked get_data.php 200 xhr jquery.min.js:4 334 B 357 ms

Comment: @UsmanKhan your code is well written but while not working so it's not correct  .. last try .. comment `/* all the foreach*/` and try the code it should work

Comment: figured out the error and it worked for me now when I added $data = array() but now the problem is that data.message is showing as undefined  :-(

Comment: why do you use processData : false in ajax

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef your last worked for me please post that as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @UsmanKhan I postead an answer with an additional information .. please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your php file ..

**1st**: Don't echo any thing with `json_encode()`

**2nd**: Comment your `foreach` loop *It may be the cause of the problem*

**So** your code should be something like this

```
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
//echo $cart->add_to_cart($pid);

$data['message']  = "<div class='message'>Your product is added to cart</div>";
$data['cart']     = '';
/*foreach($_SESSION['cart']['pid'] as $content) { 
    $prod_id          = $content['prod_id'];
    $products         = bgMysqlSelect("SELECT * FROM bg_products WHERE pid = '$prod_id'");
    $data['cart']    .= '<div class="items-sm"><div class="img-sm"><img src="../includes/uploads'.$products['pimage'].'" /></div>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<div class="cart-inf-sm"><h4>'.$products['ptitle'].'</h4>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<p><span>price :</span>$'.$products['pmsrp'].'</p>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<p><span>Qty :</span>'.$content['qty'].'</p>';
    $data['cart']    .= '<a href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div></div>';
}*/

echo json_encode($data);
```

**ِAdditional Information:**  while you have no `input[type=file]` and not passing files from js to php you can use `.serialize()` instead of `new formData()`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#addcart").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var oldval   = $('#crtcount').text();
        var form     = $(this);
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            url         : "includes/get_data.php",
            type        : "POST",
            data        : formData,
            //contentType : false,
            //cache       : false,
            //processData : false,
            dataType    : "JSON",
            success     : function(data) {
                //var data = $.parseJSON(data); // I think there is no need for this line
                $('#crtcount').html(parseInt(oldval)+1);
                $('#crtcount1').html(parseInt(oldval)+1);
                $('#cart_dt').html(data.cart);
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Comment: once last question i have to run this function so if i do not write echo will it run as i have made this just to add the product to cart $cart->add_to_cart($pid);

Comment: @UsmanKhan sure you can use it .. if this function already can save your data into databse ..  I don't know what is inside `add_to_cart()` function but you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424377/inserting-into-database-using-a-pdo ..